# Bootstrap toggle collapse unknown id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap trying to make a `data-toggle="collapse"` on the container next to the one I am clicking on. Since I am generating this list of a database outcome and this might get big I don't want to waste IDs on it.
I've already tried something like this:

```
<a class="list-group-item accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="javascript:return $(this).next();">
<div class="card-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="card-body">
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

I am missing something here, since it does not work. Any ideas on how to do this?

**Update:**
What I am looking for is to get this `href="javascript:return $(this).next();"` to target the next element.

**Update 2:**
My goal is, that a click on the link should toggle collapse on `<div class="card-collapse collapse in">`

Comment: why you tag bootstrap 4 here?

Comment: your tag `<div class="panel-collapse collapse in">` should have the attribute `id="collapse"`

Comment: @NishargShah since I am using it in here and it has a built in solution for this, but I would need to assign ids to the next items.

Comment: @LUXS `panel-body` is a class of bootstrap 3, so why you tag BS4?

Comment: @NishargShah just corrected it to `card`. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Why type of targeting do you wish to achieve?

Comment: @RubyRacer Just added an update to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution by putting a small script on that page.

```
<script>
  $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('div.collapse').slideToggle();
  });
</script>
```

Also I added `$('.collapse').slideUp();` as first line of the function to have only one item opened.

```js
$('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function() {
  if($(this).next('div.collapse').is(':hidden')) {
    $('.collapse').slideUp();
  }
  $(this).next('div.collapse').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="list-group w-100">
  <a class="list-group-item accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"><h3>Entry 1</h3></a>
  <div class="list-group-item collapse in">
    <p>Some details on entry 1.</p>
  </div>
  <a class="list-group-item accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"><h3>Entry 2</h3></a>
  <div class="list-group-item collapse in">
    <p>Some details on entry 2.</p>
  </div>
  <a class="list-group-item accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"><h3>Entry 3</h3></a>
  <div class="list-group-item collapse in">
    <p>Some details on entry 3.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  simple code , its working correctly

```js
function doit(e){
$(e.target).next().collapse('toggle')
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="doit(event);" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Link with href
  </a> 
 
<div class="collapse">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```